# What does moose scat/poop look like?

Tags: animals, moose, scat-identification

What does moose scat/poop look like and how can one distinguish it from the other similar scats namely deer and elk?

Comment: You can identify it easily by the huge, palmate antlers and the funny-shaped nose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest distinguishers of moose scat from elk and deer are size and color.

Moose scat is significantly bigger than either deer or elk scat **around the size of a very large grape and usually reddish brown** instead of black like deer or elk.

Notice both the size in comparison to the boot tracks and the reddish color,

[image: Moose Scat]

[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Snowpoop.JPG)

For comparison elk scat, (deer would be smaller still)

[image: Elk scat]

[Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Elk_pellets.jpg)